# why md5 conversion becomes different that what expected?

Tags: javascript, md5

I'm using hmac for hashing, and the md5 conversion is a 32 character hash, but the converted value in back end (.net) is a 24 character string.
I tried short md5 but the result doesn't match. is there any other md5 hashing mode with 24 characters output string?

Comment: u can try uniqueid()

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely to be the algorithm, but the encoding of the result from the algorithm.

MD5 produces 128 bits. In pure binary to byte conversion that is 16 characters (bytes).

If you encoded it into base 64 that would be 24 characters.

If you have 32 characters that suggests it is hex encoded instead.